# HttpPost добавляет суффикс к телу url

Tags: java, http, post, httpclient

Есть метод для формирования POST.

```
public void doPostRequest(Object input, String methodName) throws IOException {
        log.info("Синхронизируем добавленный в кеш объект");

        try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault()) {
            String JSON_STRING = writer.writeValueAsString(input);

            StringEntity requestEntity = new StringEntity(
                    JSON_STRING,
                    ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);

            HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(methodName);
            postMethod.setEntity(requestEntity);
            HttpResponse rawResponse = httpClient.execute(postMethod);
        }

    }
```

проблема в том что я передаю в конструктор HttpPost(methodName)

methodName - это строка такого типа

http://myservice:8180/location-service/add

а postMethod становиться равен после инициализации

http://myservice:8180/location-service/sync_api/add HTTP/1.1

вот от куда это  HTTP/1.1 берется и как его удалить??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Суффикс `HTTP/1.1` берётся из метода `toString()` класса `HttpRequestBase`, от которого унаследован класс `HttpPost`. Собственно, удалять его нет никакой необходимости, потому что это лишь удобочитаемое строковое представление класса, которое используется для отладки или логирования, а при выполнении запроса используется именно тот URL, который вы передаёте в конструктор. Но если вам этот суффикс так сильно мозолит глаза, то создайте наследника класса `HttpPost`, переопределите в нём метод `toString()` так, чтобы он выводил только URL (ну или как вам больше нравится) и пользуйтесь этим наследником вместо `HttpPost`.

Comment: большое спасибо!